# ISFORMULA function conditional formatting, exclude formulas that contain specific phrase

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I would like to highlight cells when a user enters a formula in a cell.

The issue I have is there are other cells that contain formulas in the same range. The Formula in particular is this one `=SUMIFS(B13:B99,AB13:AB99,TRUE)` The cell ranges can change, but the rest will not.

I would like to set up conditional formatting that says, If the cell contains the SUMIF string, then do not apply the conditional formatting.

The user will just be entering simple formulas. `Ex =10,000*1.34, or =5,733+2,000+1,000`. They could be putting in addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and parentheses. I don't think they would need any more functionality. So we could also use those variables as well.

The reason I cannot just manually do this, is because the sheet is dynamic and imports data. The locations of the cells I do not want to highlight are always changing.

I am open to using VBA or just regular old Excel formulas.

My current formula is simply `=ISFORMULA(B11:B99)` and it returns a value of true or false. How can I write a condition to say, if there is a formula that does not contain `SUMIF`, return true, else false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FORMULATEXT` in your condition:

```
=NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SUMIFS",FORMULATEXT(G6))))
```

This will basically look for "SUMIFS" in the text of the formula, if it is found, `ISNUMBER` will return true, since you want the opposite, the whole thing is wrapped in a `NOT`

Comment: Except this return TRUE for a cell that does not contain a formula. I was thinking `=IF(ISFORMULA(G6),IFERROR(SEARCH("sumifs(",FORMULATEXT(G6))=0,TRUE),FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you Chris. The method that @cybernetic.nomad proposed did exactly what you said, it was returning True when a cell didn't contain a formula. Your if statement solved that problem. I ended up using VBA to apply the conditional formatting to the range.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple custom function, such as:

```
Function IS_SUMIFS(r As Range) As Boolean

If r.HasFormula Then
    If InStr(r.Formula, "SUMIFS") = 0 Then IS_SUMIFS = True   'formula doesn't contain SUMIFS
End If

End Function
```